# LINQ Does not contain a definition for 'union'

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

what is wrong with this linq query that show me the error of Does not contain a definition for 'union'

```
(from rev in db.vM29s
          where Years.Contains(rev.FinancialYear) && rev.Exclude=="No"
          group rev by new { rev.RevenueCode, rev.FinancialYear } into g
 select new
 {
     Revenuecode = g.Key.RevenueCode,
     totalRevenue = g.Sum(x => x.RevenueAmount),
     RevenueEnglish = (from a in db.RevenueCodes where a._RevenueCode == g.Key.RevenueCode select a.RevenueEng).FirstOrDefault(),
     //  MinorCode = (from a in db.MinorCodes where a._MinorCode == g.Key.MinorCode select a.MinorEng),
     RevenueDari = (from a in db.RevenueCodes where a._RevenueCode == g.Key.RevenueCode select a.RevenueDari).FirstOrDefault(),
     Yearss = g.Key.FinancialYear
  }
)
.Union
(from u in db.rtastable
           where Years.Contains(u.Year)
           group u by new { u.objectcode, u.Year } into g
 select new
 {
     Revenuecode = g.Key.objectcode,
     totalRevenue = g.Sum(x => x.amount),
     RevenueEnglish = (from a in db.RevenueCodes where a._RevenueCode == g.Key.objectcode select a.RevenueEng).FirstOrDefault(),
     //  MinorCode = (from a in db.MinorCodes where a._MinorCode == g.Key.MinorCode select a.MinorEng),
     RevenueDari = (from a in db.RevenueCodes where a._RevenueCode == g.Key.objectcode select a.RevenueDari).FirstOrDefault(),
     Yearss = g.Key.Year
  }
)
.ToList();
```

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. Don't write such code in the first place. LINQ is a query language on top of an ORM. This query though has nothing to do with objects and relations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's true but how to solve this error? I think there is no error in this query but why it shows me this error?

Comment: Cast to ToList().Union(etc...) first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you included `using System.Linq;` *and* both Anonymous Types have **exactly** the same property names + property types, then what you did should work.

Yet it does not work. The solution is to check your Anonymous Types for subtle **property name differences** and/or subtle **property type differences**.

E.g. even an `int` vs a `smallint` or `double` or `decimal` will cause this build error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Switching to `.Concat()` will not fix this: it has the same (obvious) restriction that the types on both sides must be compatible.

After you fix the naming or typing problem, I would recommend that you consider switching to `.Concat()`. The reason: `.Union()` will call `.Equals()` on all objects to eliminate duplicates, but that is pointless because no two Anonymous Objects that were created independently will ever be the same object (even if their contents would be the same).

If it was your *specific intention* to eliminate duplicates, then you need to create a class that holds your data and that implements `.Equals()` in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Just learned that it's especially difficult to spot a **property type difference** with interfaces, even if they are inherited. When trying to `.Concat()` a `IList<T>` property with the `IEnumerable<T>` result of a `.Where()`. Even `TSource` parameter order didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Concat__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) or using  [addRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) if the data is allready in memory.

Comment: Why should one do that, when that produces a different result? A Concat is not a Union, not in SQL and not in Linq.

Comment: @nvoigt the c# `IEnumerable<T>.Concat<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)` is a concatenation of generic object sets. It is not the same as `string.Concat(IEnumerable<T>)` nor the SQL `CONCATENATE()`. When using EntityFramework LINQ will translate it to a SQL `UNION ALL` equivalent. Where a LINQ Union will translate to SQL `UNION DISTINCT`.